# Is it possible to upgrade from Postgres 8.3.3 with existing databases to 8.4.2 (installed windows vista)?

Tags: postgresql, migration, database, installation

I'm considering upgrade from Postgres 8.3.3 to 8.4.2 on my machine (it has Windows Vista).

Windows Installer (one click installer) for Postgres 8.4.2 that can be downloaded from enterprisedb.com offers only fresh install (it does not recognizes my current installation of v8.3.3).

Is it possible to upgrade with all existing databases converted and visible (automatically migrated?) in new version just after upgrade? Or I have to do something more - backup/restore all my databases manually?

Comment: [Upgrading PostgreSQL 8.1 to 8.4 on CentOS 5.5](http://blog.lystor.org.ua/2010/05/upgrading-postgresql-81-to-84-centos-55.html)

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: you need to pg_dump, install fresh 8.4, and then load.

No so simple answer - you can use pg_migrator to do inplace binary files upgrade, but i haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried pg_migrator and:

1. Latest version (8.4.11) is not appropriate for my migration tast - it allows migration to 8.5 but I need migration to 8.4.2.

   `Performing Consistency Checks
   Checking old data directory (c:\program files\postgresql\8.3\data)ok
   Checking new data directory (c:\program files\postgresql\8.4\data)ok`

   `This binary was built using 8.5 PostgreSQL sources; it must be
   built using 8.4 PostgreSQL sources to match the new cluster.`

but... there is no info on pg_migrator home page what version of migrator is for what target version of Postgres. I've downloaded and installed v8.4.4 and it seems proper version, but here is what i says:

`mapped win32 error code 2 to 2
     Old and new pg_controldata date/time storage types do not match.`

`You will need to rebuild the new server with configure
     --disable-integer-datetimes or get server binaries built
     with those options.`

So, it is not so automatic for me. I think old classic pg_dump / restore will do better.